# Storing files to S3 : local file vs HDFS

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

**Background**

Simple age old problem of uploading files to s3 using java with a slight twist

S3 does not support streaming (AFAIK) so data needs to be grouped into some appropriate sized files before it is uploaded.

While creating these temporary files mentioned above there are some options as far as location is concerned

1. Locally in some designated directories
2. Locally in HDFS (if something like that is possible, I don't know even H from Hadoop)
3. To HDFS in hadoop cluster

**Question**

1. Which one is likely to be faster?
2. Is there advantage in using HDFS (either locally or cluster) vs local FS, HDFS being closer in nature to S3 format?

**Tech and infrastructure**

EC2, linux, java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough disk space locally, just do it locally. Otherwise, you can merge the data into the stores you need on HDFS and then upload them. However, HDFS should not be your first resort here.

Comment: May I know why do you not recommend HDFS ?

Comment: HDFS just isn't really designed for this and it'd be faster to do all of the file manipulation on disk if possible.

Comment: Yes, ended up using local FS and uploading to S3 final compressed file